# How do I utilize Solrnet in a Master->Slave environment?

Tags: c#, solrnet

I am currently getting Solr implemented for our company to replace our GSA systems and am in the middle of implementation.  I am using SolrNet for the client access code to interface with Solr via C#.

Right now I am following the wiki and instantiating the Solr configuration via `Startup.Init<XosContentDocument>("http://localhost:8080/solr/xosContent");`.  I then retrieve the solr collection via `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<XosContentDocument>>();`

This works for now (and yes, I am going to move the url to a configuration setting so it's not directly in code) but I am confused on how this will work once we add redundancy.

My plan is to get two Solr instances up, one being the Master and the 2nd being a slave, and having an internally accessible domain name (e.g. solr.internal.whatever.com) load balance between the two for read requests.  However, from my understanding of researching replication of Solr I must only do writes against the master, as any writes that go to the slave will be discarded upon subsequent replications.

Therefore, I really need 2 instances of an `ISolrOperations<XosContentDocument>>`, 1 that points the the address of the query load balancer and another that points directly to the address of the master solr instance.  Since the only way I have seen to initialize and retrieve an `ISolrOperations<T>` is to use `Startup.Init<T>(); ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<T>>`, how do I accomplish this dual nature?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MultiCoreAccess

Comment: So would I pretend it's another core (even though it's the same exact core) and just have one point directly to the master server and the other to the load balancer url?

Comment: The process Mauricio pointed you to is the same for multiple cores or instances of Solr. Yes, you would have one pointed to the master for write operations and one pointed to the load balancer for query operations.

Answer (score 0):

The process to utilize SolrNet in a Master/Slave environment is the same as the one used for a multicore environment. 
You can read more about it here : https://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MultiCoreAccess

they way I've done it to be more exact is to have a core pointed to the master for indexation and the other pointed to othe slave for querying.